# Sci-Fi Novel: Story about woman with nano bots repaired after emp weapon

Tags: story-identification

All I can remember is that she had healing/repair nanobots, and that after the EMP weapon she was killed and almost all the nanobots died. But some survived and healed her. After that she was immune to emp weapons because the nanobots had evolved somehow.

I know it's not *World Without End* by Fergus Gwynplaine MacIntyre or *The Last Mortal Man* by Syne Mitchell

Update:
@Valorum, I looked at the list, here is what I know:
I read it about 15 to 20 years ago. The story was in English. I am 99% sure it was an American author.
What stood out for me was she was supposed to be dead, along with the nanobots, but some survived and they could repair her again. If I remember correctly it was a slow repair, eye, then brain, etc. something like that.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum have gone through the checklist and added the info to my main question, thanks!

Comment: "Legacy", a short story by Todd Johnson in Bolos book 2 The Unconquerable is similar, although the main character doesn't survive at the end. Was yours a complete novel, or in a collection?

Comment: @Brian The book I read was a complete novel. But I've purchased the book you mentioned and loving the stories! Thanks for a great new find!

Comment: I could be absolutely completely wrong but I think her name in the book could have been Deloris or Doris....